# TChromium Browser and authentication proxy. FMX

Tags: delphi, authentication, proxy, firemonkey

> **How to add a proxy with authorization in TChromium.**

```
 192.168.0.1:8080:login:password
```

FMX. Delphi.

[There is no this property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWemg.png)

Comment: There's a group of properties prefixed by _Proxy_.

Comment: Could you point me to them? No matter how much I tried and could not find it

Comment: `TChromium` contains them. They are just public, not published.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWemg.png

Comment: Aha, you're not using CEF4Delphi. You're using DCEF3, don't you?

Comment: Sorry, Then such a question? Where can I find CEF4Delphi for FMX?

Comment: I don't know. Sorry from my side. I missed that FMX thing assuming CEF4Delphi :)

Comment: Thank you, for your answers. Could you tell me how to make the browser support proxy with authorization using FMX

Comment: I'd write a handler for the `OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing` (`CefOnBeforeCommandLineProcessing` variable) and append [command line arguments](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-proxy-resolution) as described. The rest is about handling `OnGetAuthCredentials` event.